# MIPS Removing a value from an array efficiently

Tags: arrays, mips

I am coding a poker deck in MIPS Mars.

Below is the array that contains the deck of cards.

```
cards:  .asciiz "2S","2C","2D","2H",
            "3S","3C","3D","3H",
            "4S","4C","4D","4H",
            "5S","5C","5D","5H",
            "6S","6C","6D","6H",
            "7S","7C","7D","7H",
            "8S","8C","8D","8H",
            "9S","9C","9D","9H",
            "10S","10C","10D","10H",
            "JS","JC","JD","JH",
            "QS","QC","QD","QH",
            "KS","KC","KD","KH",
            "AS","AC","AD","AH"
```

As random card is chosen and passed out to the player, I want to remove that card from the array.
To achieve that I thought about:

```
#use recursion to store the cards in another array up to the point of random card
#skip that random card space and continue storing.
#prepare to pass out next random card by decrementing random gen value by 1
```

This is what I can think of right now, however would like to know if anyone can think of more efficient method.

Comment: sounds painful. why not just randomly shuffle that card list? then "dealing" a card is a simple matter of pulling whatever the last card is off the end of the list. no need for copying the list around when you deal "from the middle".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order isn't important (and it doesn't sound like it is), you can just move the last card "in the deck" into the position occupied by the card removed.  If you want to be able to re-use the deck in the future, you could swap those 2 positions, so that you always have all 52 cards in the array.